# Dim screen light even though I have brightness on high

Tags: 16.04, brightness, backlight

So I currently am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the brightness button registers my screen brightness on high, however, the actual brightness that I see is the lowest. I've tried using terminal codes to manually change the brightness but that lead me to crash my previous version. Which meant that I had to format my laptop and it's still dim. I can't seem to find any way to actually fix the brightness. I've suffered this issue in Windows, but it was easily fixed by changing the graphics card to PnP monitor then back to my Intel card fixing the issue. With Ubuntu I can't seem to find a way to do that, unless I'm not looking in the right places. [image: this is my current state of brightness even though it says high.]

UPDATE: I have reached rock bottom. I've looked over videos on YouTube about changing the driver from open source to proprietary, tested and still didn't work. I've created a conf file to change the brightness when I reboot still no success. Currently my only option which I know will work is formatting my laptop to Windows. I can easily change the brightness from there. However, I don't have an image of Windows on a CD or USB. So right now I need help ASAP please.

UPDATE 2: So I found a downloadable Windows 10 .iso file. So I gave up on Ubuntu. Note to whoever sees this; don't use Ubuntu unless you know what you're doing. Other wise just accept your fate and stick to your current OS even if it's killing you.

Comment: what did you try already that broke things? did you try editing `/etc/sysfs.conf` ?

Comment: If you can make it out, what is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`?

Comment: @Zanna I did do that, which lead my computer to crash. I would restart and it would show me 'bbw switch'.

Comment: @Zzzach... How would I do that?

Comment: @Zzzach... So I did that, I don't see any output unless you're talking about which graphics driver is being used then it says 'Lenovo 3rd gen core processor graphics controller' and 'Lenovo GF108M (GeForce GT 635M)

Comment: I have quite the opposite situation. My screen is as bright as the sun and the battery is completely dry in like 15 minutes.  Hope that would cheer you up a bit, mate!

Comment: @ipselute hahaha. I wish I had mine like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not a brightness issue, rather just your backlight seems to be off. Finagle your way to a terminal and run:

`xset dpms force on`

You might also have an <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> key that will do the trick. My backlight toggle, for example, is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Comment: So I did the xset in terminal and no success. Was that the full code or just part of it? I don't have a function key to toggle the brightness. It only changes the level of brightness.

Comment: That was the full command. I'll see if I can't find another solution.